# how to find child (not all descendants) elements via an existing element (not xpath)

Tags: java, css, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find the children of an already found element. The problem I am having is that I can seem to only get all descendants of an existing element.

For example, given the following HTML snippet (you may recognize this as a bootstrap dropdown menu).

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li>
      <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I already have the existing WebElement to the dropdown menu

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElementBy(By.cssSelector(".dropdown > .dropdown-menu");
```

And I am trying to get a handle to all the child li's of the outer most menu. Originally I was doing the following

```
List<WebElement> menuItems = dropdown.findElements(By.cssSelector(" > li > a");
```

assuming it would result in a final selector being built

```
.dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a
```

However, this throws an exception

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: An invalid or illegal string was specified
```

Doing the following doesn't throw an exception but returns all descendants ... not just the children. The cound of menuItems is 10 instead of 5.

```
List<WebElement> menuItems = dropdown.findElements(By.cssSelector("li > a");
```

So I guess my ultimate question is there a way to use By.cssSelector to get just the direct children of an already found node?

XPATH is not an allowable solution.

Comment: I don't know whether this would work...try `dropdown.findElements(By.cssSelector(".dropdown > li >a"))`

Comment: @MrTi ... i will give that a try tomorrow. maybe the findElements includes itself in the context of the search.

Comment: What happens if you run `$$(".dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a")` in Chrome's Developer Console? It'll run the CSS selector for you and return the elements it finds.

Comment: How come xpath isn't an allowable solution?

Comment: @Arran ... using that selector in a browser would work just fine.

Comment: @vincebowdren ... i've been using webdriver/selenium for 5 years now and through my experience, xpath works awesome until you get to an IE browser. We want to make sure we can write a single test for all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about change the logic a bit?

You have a `WebElement` called `dropdown`, but it is defined as class `dropdown-menu` in the DOM. Why not define `dropdown` as `div.dropdown` instead of `ul.dropdown-menu`? Then your issue can be solved.

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".dropdown");
List<WebElement> menuItems = dropdown.findElements(By.cssSelector(".dropdown-menu[role='menu'] > li > a");
List<WebElement> subMenuItems = dropdown.findElements(By.cssSelector(".dropdown-submenu li > a");
```

Comment: i thought about something similar to this ... e.g. tagging the menu with the level they are found at, but I was thinking that what I am trying to do should be completely possible with webdriver (by that i mean getting the direct children of an already found element).

Comment: @loesak: Actually this sounds like a Selenium bug, or this can't be implemented due to design. Might want to check the source code and see the underlying method.

Comment: so far this is the best answer that gets me around the issue however it does not fully resolve the fundamental issue. I've submitted a bug back to selenium (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6050) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just combine them?

```
List<WebElement> menuItems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".dropdown > .dropdown-menu  > li > a");
```

Comment: Maybe i forgot to mention but the grabbing of the elements are in different classes. The dropdown menu WebElement is passed around. By the time i need the dropdown items, i know nothing about how the dropdown menu was found.